# Why is std::isgraph throwing an exception in std::use_facet?

Tags: c++, character-encoding, locale

```
bool foo (char32_t code_point)
{
    static std::locale loc ("en_US.utf8");
    return std::isgraph (code_point, loc);
}

foo ('B');
```

This throws an exception:

```
  /**
   *  @brief  Return a facet.
   *  @ingroup locales
   *
   *  use_facet looks for and returns a reference to a facet of type Facet
   *  where Facet is the template parameter.  If has_facet(locale) is true,
   *  there is a suitable facet to return.  It throws std::bad_cast if the
   *  locale doesn't contain a facet of type Facet.
   *
   *  @tparam  _Facet  The facet type to access.
   *  @param  __loc  The locale to use.
   *  @return  Reference to facet of type Facet.
   *  @throw  std::bad_cast if @p __loc doesn't contain a facet of type _Facet.
  */
  template<typename _Facet>
    const _Facet&
    use_facet(const locale& __loc)
    {
      const size_t __i = _Facet::id._M_id();
      const locale::facet** __facets = __loc._M_impl->_M_facets;
      if (__i >= __loc._M_impl->_M_facets_size || !__facets[__i])
        __throw_bad_cast();
#if __cpp_rtti
      return dynamic_cast<const _Facet&>(*__facets[__i]);
#else
      return static_cast<const _Facet&>(*__facets[__i]);
#endif
    }
```

It calls `__throw_bad_cast()` because `__i==46` which equals `_M_facets_size`.

Note: the documentation does say `It throws std::bad_cast if the locale doesn't contain a facet of type Facet.`

But I don't know that means.

On my Ubuntu, `locale -a` includes `en_US.utf8`, and the `loc` structure looks reasonable in the debugger:

[image]

Why does `isgraph` throw an exception?

Comment: My guess: the locale has `ctype<char>` facet installed, but not `ctype<char32_t>`. The standard only [requires](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype) the existence of `ctype<char>` and `ctype<wchar_t>`

Comment: What does it mean to install a facet?

Comment: `std::locale` has [a constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/locale) that takes a facet as a parameter, if you want to add a custom one.